# Проблемы при обработке regex'ами вставляемого с clipboard хтмл контента

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь на Джаваскрипте обработать хтмл контент, скопированный со стороннего сайта и вставляемый с буфера обмена в элементы моей страницы, которые имеют `contenteditable="true"`

```
var allEditableWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('*[contenteditable="true"]');
for(var i = 0; i < allEditableWrappers.length; i++) {
    allEditableWrappers[i].addEventListener('paste', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pastedContent = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/<!--StartFragment-->/g, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/<!--EndFragment-->/g, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/style="[^"]*"/g, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/class="[^"]*"/g, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/id="[^"]*"/g, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/data-(.*?)="[^"]*"/g, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/<div.*?>/si, '');
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/<\/div>/si, '');
        if(pastedContent.indexOf('<p>') === -1) {
            var pastedContent = '<p>'+pastedContent+'</p>';
        }
        var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/®/g, '&reg;');
        this.innerHTML = pastedContent;
    });
}
```

**Первая проблема** в том что бывает на сайте-доноре выделяю и копирую только один абзац и теги абзаца не копируются в clipboard, только текст. В таком случае при вставке нужно добавить обвертку `<p>` и `</p>`. Как видно по коду, пытаюсь это сделать через:

```
if(pastedContent.indexOf('<p>') === -1) {
    var pastedContent = '<p>'+pastedContent+'</p>';
}
```

Но данная "обвертка" во-первых кроме тегов `<p>` и `</p>` почему то добавляет и пустые строки, которые не нужны, и текст разбивается на части, обвернутые в span'ы. А во-вторых если на сайте-доноре выделить несколько разных блоков и при этом теги абзацов копируются в clipboard, то "обвертка", которая в принципе не должна в таком случае добавляться, почему то вставляет пустые абзацы в начале и в конце вставляемого контента.

И **вторая проблема** в том что не могу заменить специальные символы. Например строка

```
var pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/®/g, '&reg;');
```

почему то не заменяет `®` на `&reg;`. Хотя перед самой вставкой `console.log()` отображает `&reg;` как и нужно. Такое впечатление что Хром возвращает назад `®` в момент когда вставляю контент в элемент с `contenteditable="true"` или причина другая, не знаю...

Тестирую копируя инфо со страницы [www.promat.ru/ru-ru/products/accessories/promaseal-lfc](http://www.promat.ru/ru-ru/products/accessories/promaseal-lfc)

Например копирую только абзац под фото *"Материал PROMASEAL®-LFC содержит..."*. При вставке получаю текст со своей "обверткой", но с пустыми строками и разбитый спанами. Потом например копирую начиная от этого абзаца и заканчивая всей таблицой снизу. Получаю при вставке пустые абзацы вначале и вконце.

ps. Читал о том что regex для парсинга хтмл не самый лучший вариант, но все же интересует решение вышеописанных проблем с тем что есть

Comment: Можете показать пример текста, который вы обрабатываете?

Comment: @Yuri с дивами проблему решил, добавил к вопросу исправленный код и ссылку на страницу-донор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var allEditableWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('*[contenteditable="true"]');
for (var i = 0; i < allEditableWrappers.length; i++) {
  allEditableWrappers[i].addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Соберём все регулярные выражения в одно
    var pastedContent = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html').replace(/\<\!\-\-(?:Start|End)Fragment\-\-\>|(?:style|class|id|data-(.*?))\=\"[^"]*\"|\<\/?div.*?\>/g, '');

    // Сделаем поиск p по регулярному выражению
    if (!/<p.*>/.exec(pastedContent)) {
      pastedContent = '<p>' + pastedContent + '</p>';
    };
    
    // Суть в том, что вы заменяли ® на этот же символ HTML кодом. Так как консоль не может преобразовывать HTML коды в символы, то вам выводило как нужно. Но как только вы вставляли код в HTML, он у вас преобразовывался обратно в символ.
    // Чтобы отобразить как нужно, я заменил первый символ кода символ на код символа. Т.е. & на &amp;
    pastedContent = pastedContent.replace(/\®/g, '&amp;reg;');

    this.innerHTML = pastedContent;
  });
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable="true"] {
  min-width: 80xp;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```